# Суфікс *юва* і дієприкметники

Tags: дієприкметники, суфікси

Чому суфікс ***юва*** випадає якщо перетворити слово **хвилювати** на активний дієприкметнік теперішнього часу **хвилюючий**?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть edit у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти! Скажу точніше: уточність, будь ласка, чому вважаєте,

Comment: що суфікс юва не має випадати. Поки ставлю мінус. По мірі редаґування посту будемо бачити, що робити з ним.

Comment: Мій вчитель української мови казав що не може відповісти на це запитання. Моя ціль це дізнатися чи на це питання взагалі є відповідь.

Comment: Тобто, нас вчили прибирати закінчення і потім добавляти потрібні суфікси для творення дієприкметників.

Comment: тоді пропоную вам ось що: 1. пошукайте в правописі / загалом в інтернеті правила творення активних дієприкметників. 2. напишіть у запитанні, що ви питали у вчителя, він не зміг дати відповіді, ви пошукали в інтернеті, і знайшли ось таку інформацію. Вичерпної відповіді на ваше запитання та інформація не дає, то ви б хотіли уточнити те й те. Таке запитання буде прийнятним для спільноти.

Comment: редагувати запитання можна через кнопку edit під ним. Ми справді раді вас вітати. Просто ознайомлюємо з правилами спільноти, щоб у подальшому плідніше співпрацювати)

Comment: Дякую за допомогу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вважаю, що це запитання цілком зрозуміле.

Автор має на увазі, що канонічна форма дієприкметника формується із дієслова заміною суфікса `-а(ти)/-я(ти)` на `-уч(ий)/-юч(ий)`. Але є дієслова, що мають канонічну форму з суфіксом, який зазвичай позначає протяжність дії `-увати/-ювати` (відсутня форма *«хвиляти»*), і цим самим вводять автора в оману. Власне, це і є відповідь на запитання.

До речі, саме цей фактор використовується лінґвістами, які виступають проти активних дієприкметників в українській мові взагалі.

Comment: Є хоч одне дієслово, в якому при творенні активного дієприкметника _-ва-_ зберігається?

Comment: @Sasha, якщо запитання до мене, то я не стверджував, що воно зберігається. Менше з тим — *«забуваючий»*. І ще *«охрєнєваючий»*. :-)

Comment: Вболіваючий, зігріваючий — виходить, є навіть у літературних дієсловах. Знати б тепер, від чого це залежить (чи зберігається _-ва-_). Якщо чесно, я зовсім не зрозумів ані сенсу запитання, ані сенсу відповіді (але не кажу, що щось не так, може, це я сьогодні не в тямі).

Comment: @Sasha, це нечесно! :-) У запитанні йшлося про `-ува- / -юва-`, а ваші приклади — `-іва-`. Тим більше, що існує канонічна, безсуфіксова форма *«гріти»*.

Comment: «Охрєнєваючий» — теж не _-ува-_. _Забуваючий_ (помітив це редагування лише зараз), а також _недочуваючий/розсуваючий_ — не певен, що підходять, бо не дуже тямлю, де тут корінь переходить у суфікс.

Comment: Re: *де корінь переходить у суфікс* — напевно, *бу(ти), чу(ти), су(ну)(ти)*. До речі, за аналогією ще пригадалися *да(ти)—роздавати*, але *роздаючий*, а також *кувати—куючий*. Коротше, чим більше таких слів спадає на думку, тим більше переконуєшся у правоті тих, кому активні дієприкметники не подобаються.

Comment: Але ж дієприкметриками це не обмежується. Є ще дієприслівники, що в цьому випадку за способом творення аналогічні дієприкметникам. А проти дієприслівників, наскільки я знаю, жодних застережень немає.